# Erro de string em uma função em Python 3

Tags: python, string

Quando eu tento rodar a def da um erro na parte do `texto[x][y-1]`, dando o seguinte:

```
erro:TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

```
def moveJogador(mapa, mov):
    if mov == "c":
        for y in range(len (mapa)-1):
            for x in range(len(mapa[0])-1):
                if texto[x][y] == JOGADOR_NA_MARCA:
                    texto[x][y-1] = ("@")  #Aqui está o erro de string
                    texto[x][y] = " "
                    print(mapa)   
    return None

movimento = input("Digite d | e | c | b | v | s [dir, esq, cima, baixo, voltar, sair]: ")

moveJogador(texto, movimento)
```

Comment: Você está tentando adicionar um item e não uma string, dentro de uma string. Tente colocar só o "@" ou "(@)" para atribuir o valor ao texto.

Comment: Podes mostrar a definição de 'texto'?

Answer (score 3):

O erro demonstra exatamente o que está acontecendo:
em Python, strings são objetos imutáveis - isso é em contraste com C,
por exemplo em que "strings" são apenas um nome conveniente para uma
região da memória que é tratada como uma sequência de dados
do tamanho de um byte. 
(Daí, você pode fazer `char *a = "abcde"; a[0] = 'f';` em C,
ele troca o byte na primeira posição da memória apontada
pela variável "a")

Em Python há um outro tipo de dado que pode ser usado da mesma forma
que strings em C: mutável, e com um mapeamento mais ou menos
conveniente e direto entre números na faixa 0-255 e objetos
string de comprimento "1" (isso em Python 2.x - em Python 3.x,
o mapeamento para texto deve ser explícito) - 
é o bytearray.

Então, em vez de criar suas linhas no mapa usando algo como:

texto.append("                @                       ")
use:
texto.append(bytearray("                            @                    ")
e você poderá endereçar e alterar valores individuais lá dentro.

Essa é a solução mais rápida para o coigo que você já tiver pronto - 
na verdade, a melhor solução par ao seu projeto é criar uma nova classe para
conter seu mapa (em vez de ter um mapa composto de listas e strings, em que
funções externas atuam para checar o conteúdo e fazer alterações).

Com uma classe próprimaa, e implementando os métodos `__getitem__` e `__setitem__` você pode ter um mapa "esperto" que saiba ele mesmo localizar o jogador, se apagar, se preencher com um valor.

Apenas tome o cuidado de assumir que os endereços passados para o get e set/item sejam sequências de dois valores, e você pode fazer algo direto assim:

```
TAMANHO = (80, 25)
class MeuMapa(object):
    def __init__(self, tamanho=TAMANHO):
        # estrutura de dados interna, composta de listas de listas, pré-preenchidas com espaços
        self.dados_internos = ([" ",] * tamanho[0]) * tamanho[1]
        self.tamanho = tamanho
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.dados_internos[index[0]][index[1]]
    def __setitem__(self, index, valor):
        return self.dados_internos[index[0]][index[1]] = valor


texto = MeuMapa()
texto[10,10] = "@"
```

Note que com essa implementação mínima, vocẽ já pode referenciar objetos no mapa usando uma única busca por índice, em vez de duas em sequência - deixando o seu código de acesso ao mapa muito mais limpo - Um método "find_player" ou "encontra_jogador" pode ser escrito de forma igualmente simples, e ser re-utilizado para cada comparação de seu "move jogador" - -o código que voce postou implica em fazer dois "for" aninhados para *cada* opção de movimento - com a classe acima, mais um método como:

```
def encontra_jogador(self):
    for y, linha in enumerate(self.dados_internos):
        for x, valor in enumerate(linha):
            if valor == JOGADOR_NA_MARCA:
                return x, y
```

O que lhe permitirá fazer:

```
x, y = texto.encontra_jogador()
print (x, y)
(10,10)
```